# Unexplainable memory leak C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement Shared Pointer which class name is SharedPtr in the code below. But I've got a problem with strange memory leaks. If I create new object like this:

```cpp
SharedPtr* P = new SharedPtr(new double(30));
```

And then delete it

```cpp
delete P;
```

Everything goes right.
But if I create it like this:

```cpp
SharedPtr P1(new double(10));
```

I get memory leaks.

What am I doing wrong?

I've checked if destructor is called and memory is getting free, but I still get memmory leaks

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef> // int
#include <cstring> // strlen, strcpy

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define DBG_NEW new ( _NORMAL_BLOCK , __FILE__ , __LINE__ )
// Replace _NORMAL_BLOCK with _CLIENT_BLOCK if you want the
// allocations to be of _CLIENT_BLOCK type
#else
#define DBG_NEW new
#endif

using namespace std;

struct SharedPtr
{
  double* ptr;
  int* counter;

  explicit SharedPtr(double* ptr = 0) : ptr(ptr)
  {
    counter = ptr ? DBG_NEW int(1) : 0;
  }
  ~SharedPtr()
  {
    if (!ptr)
      return;
    (*counter)--;
    if (!(*counter))
    {
      delete ptr;
      delete counter;
    }
  }
  SharedPtr(const SharedPtr& P) : counter(P.counter), ptr(P.ptr)
  {
    if (ptr)
      (*counter)++;
  }
  SharedPtr& operator=(const SharedPtr& P)
  {
    if (this != &P)
    {
      if (ptr)
      {
        (*counter) -= 1;
        if ((*counter) == 0)
        {
          delete ptr;
          delete counter;

          ptr = 0;
          counter = 0;
        }

      }
      if (P.ptr)
      {
        (*P.counter)++;
        ptr = P.ptr;
        counter = P.counter;
      }
    }

    return *this;
  }
};
int main()
{
  SharedPtr P1(DBG_NEW double(10)); //Leak
  SharedPtr P2(DBG_NEW double(20)); //Leak
 // SharedPtr P3 = P1, P4 = P1, P5 = P1;


  SharedPtr* P = DBG_NEW SharedPtr(DBG_NEW double(30)); 
  delete P; //No leak

  _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
  return 0;
}
```

I expect program finish without any leaks in any case, but i get some if I create pointer object without allocating memory

```
Z:\T00TEST\T00TEST\T00TEST.cpp(26) : {159} normal block at 0x00BB6110, 4 bytes long.
 Data: <    > 01 00 00 00 
Z:\T00TEST\T00TEST\T00TEST.cpp(101) : {158} normal block at 0x00BBEA18, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <      4@> 00 00 00 00 00 00 34 40 
Z:\T00TEST\T00TEST\T00TEST.cpp(26) : {157} normal block at 0x00BBD898, 4 bytes long.
 Data: <    > 01 00 00 00 
Z:\T00TEST\T00TEST\T00TEST.cpp(100) : {156} normal block at 0x00BBEB30, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <      $@> 00 00 00 00 00 00 24 40
```

Comment: Maybe it's because `P1` and `P2` are destoyed after `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` is called?

Comment: *Why* are you not using `std` smart pointers???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

At this time, both of your `P1` and `P2` shared pointers still exist and in scope, and maintain a reference count. They are not destroyed (but your dynamically-allocated pointer is `delete`d and destroyed). So, you shouldn't be surprised that your debugging library still finds some allocated memory. You called this debugging function before `P1` and `P2` **get destroyed when your `main()` returns**.

Destroy P1 and P2 first, then try again. The easiest way to do this is to simply put them in an inner scope.

```
{
  SharedPtr P1(DBG_NEW double(10)); //Leak
  SharedPtr P2(DBG_NEW double(20)); //Leak

// The rest of your code

}
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

Answer (score 3):

Objects created in a certain scope are destroyed at the end of that scope.

So `P1` and `P2` will be destroyed at the end of `main()`, after the call to `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()`.

So it will report them as leaks since they haven't been destroyed yet.

Move the test into a separate function, i.e. `test()` and call it from `main()` like this:

```
void test()
{
  SharedPtr P1(DBG_NEW double(10));
  SharedPtr P2(DBG_NEW double(20));

  SharedPtr* P = DBG_NEW SharedPtr(DBG_NEW double(30)); 
  delete P; //No leak
}

int main()
{
  test();
  _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```